# Installing ColdFusion 11 on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, coldfusion

I have been trying to install ColdFusion 11 on Mac OS X 10.10, 64 bit (Yosemite), but it fails. When I open the terminal and type java -version it says:

java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

I think that this means that I have the 1.7 jdk?

I download the latest install for Mac OS X yesterday from Adobe, and the first part of the install seems to install (running the app cases no errors), but it does not write anything to the httpd.conf file. I do add the index.cfm to the  DirectoryIndex in the httpd.conf file . Then when I go to the admin URL it just downloads the index.cfm file. This is when I use the build in web server (port 8500).

When I try to install on the localhost (port 80) the CFIDE is not written to /Library/WebServer/Documents folder. This is where I want to install CF 11.

As anybody been able to install CF 11 to mac OS X Yosemite?

Thanks,
Johnny

Answer (score 2):

I got this up and running last week. This article describes how I set up my MBP for development with CF 10:

http://iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/27/Installing-ColdFusion-10-on-OSX-108-Mountain-Lion

I uninstalled CF 10 and installed CF 11 in its place. Only had a few hiccups with the installation.

Make sure you choose the Tomcat / Apache setup. Use `/private/etc/apache2` as the config folder. Once you hit the Admin URL, you may hit a `NullPointerException` error. If so, take a look at [this article](http://blog.immanuelnoel.com/2014/06/06/fixing-the-null-pointer-exception-on-coldfusion/) for how to fix it. CF will install CFIDE where it needs it, not where you want it. You can create a map to it in your vhosts.conf file.